# Dynamic cols and rows in Bootstrap/Rails

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I have a layout conundrum here. I have a Ruby block iterating through records and placing each one in a col-md-4 which is inside a row.

```
<div class="row">
 <% @object.each do |object| %>
   <div class="col-md-4">
    <%= object %>
   </div>
 <% end %>
</div>
```

If I have 6 records I will get this result (I'll just provide HTML):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>
```

What can I do to get this result?

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>
```

Can I do this with Ruby or would jQuery be a better fit here. Would I need to do some kind of count?

Comment: I have answered similar question before. Take a look [on it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25961186/solution-to-break-table-td-into-rows-of-6-or-less/25961402#25961402).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `each_slice(x)` to break up your `@object` in sets of 3. You then include your rows with each iteration and then loop through the objects to display the object.

```
 <% @object.each_slice(3) do |objects| %>
  <div class="row">
    <% objects.each do |object| %>
     <div class="col-md-4">
      <%= object %>
     </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: thanks, that was just what i was looking for, a ruby solution :-)

Answer (score 0):

Easy

```
<div class="row">
    <% @object.each_with_index do |v,i| %>
        <% if i % 4 == 0 %>
            </div><div class="row">
        <% end %>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <%= object %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: The first index is `0`. Does it then add an empty `div` in the first iteration?

Comment: @crackedmind `@object.to_enum.with_index(1) do |v, i|` would be better.